# ECharts - how to inject value from props?

Tags: vue.js, echarts

I have the following Chart Component:

```
<template>
  <div class="gauge-chart">
    <chart :options="options"></chart>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    chartValue: { type: Number, required: true },
    chartName: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  data: () => ({
    options: {
      series: [
        {
          type: "gauge",
          startAngle: 180,
          endAngle: 0,
          min: 1,
          max: 5,
          splitNumber: 8,
          axisLine: {
            lineStyle: {
              width: 6,
              color: [
                [0.25, "#7CFFB2"],
                [0.5, "#58D9F9"],
                [0.75, "#FDDD60"],
                [1, "#FF6E76"],
              ],
            },
          },
          pointer: {
            icon: "arrow",
            offsetCenter: [0, "-30%"],
            itemStyle: {
              color: "auto",
            },
          },
          axisTick: {
            length: 12,
            lineStyle: {
              color: "auto",
              width: 1,
            },
          },
          splitLine: {
            length: 20,
            lineStyle: {
              color: "auto",
              width: 5,
            },
          },
          title: {
            fontSize: 30,
          },
          data: [
            {
              value: this.chartValue,
              name: this.chartName,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  }),
};
</script>
```

As you can see I am tryng to inject chartValue and chartName props into options.series.data.value and options.series.data.name respectively.

The values for the properties are coming from

```
<GaugeChart chartName="Sleep" :chartValue="2" />
```

At the moment the values are hardcoded, but eventually they will be dynamic.
However it keep throwing the following error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'chartName' of undefined"
> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'chartValue' of undefined"

I have done a colsole.log of both properties and they come up as "Sleep" and 2. I have also done a typeof on both property names and they both come up as String and Number, respectively.

Could somebody tell me where I am going wrong please?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did u print the console nd see...inside the chart Component?

Comment: it should be like this => `<GaugeChart chartName="Sleep" chartValue="2" />` assuming `Sleep` and `2` are static data

Comment: @Amaarrockz I did it inside a mounted hoock inside the Chart Component.

Comment: @NileshPatel without the semicolon in front of chartValue the 2 will be passed as a string ("2"). But I want it passed as a number (2).

Comment: @MikeyKatholnig create a property in data object `data(){ return val: 2}` and use it like `<GaugeChart chartName="Sleep" :chartValue="val" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use 'this' operator inside an arrow function so define your data section as a normal function

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    chartValue: { type: Number, required: true },
    chartName: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  data() {
   return {
    options: {
      series: [
        {
          type: "gauge",
          startAngle: 180,
          endAngle: 0,
          min: 1,
          max: 5,
          splitNumber: 8,
          axisLine: {
            lineStyle: {
              width: 6,
              color: [
                [0.25, "#7CFFB2"],
                [0.5, "#58D9F9"],
                [0.75, "#FDDD60"],
                [1, "#FF6E76"],
              ],
            },
          },
          pointer: {
            icon: "arrow",
            offsetCenter: [0, "-30%"],
            itemStyle: {
              color: "auto",
            },
          },
          axisTick: {
            length: 12,
            lineStyle: {
              color: "auto",
              width: 1,
            },
          },
          splitLine: {
            length: 20,
            lineStyle: {
              color: "auto",
              width: 5,
            },
          },
          title: {
            fontSize: 30,
          },
          data: [
            {
              value: this.chartValue,
              name: this.chartName,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  };
 }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the prop in following manner:

```
<GaugeChart chart-name="Sleep" chart-value="2" />
```

[Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case)

> HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret any uppercase characters as lowercase.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But even just like this ```<GaugeChart name="Sleep" :value="2" />``` it doesn't work